# Reversing an integer and finding whether it's a palindrome Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that finds whether is a palindrome or not.  I have this code and can't figure out for the life of me why it won't work.  It runs but only returns that the number is not a palindrome regardless of whether it is or not

```
def reverse(number):
    reverse = 0    
    while number > 0:
        endDigit = number % 10
        reverse = (reverse*10) + endDigit
        number = number // 10

def isPalindrome(number):
    reverse(number)
    original = number    
    if original == reverse:
        print("yep, it's a Palindrome")
    else:
        print("sorry man, not a Palindrome...")

def main():
    number = eval(input("Please enter a number and I'll check if it's a Palindrome: "))
    isPalindrome(number)
main()
```

Comment: Your `reverse()` function calculates the reversed number in a local variable, which is not returned or otherwise made available outside of the function.  There is no point in calling this function at all.

Comment: So how would I make it so that the reverse() function is made available in the isPalindrome() function?

Comment: also I just realized that you're right, the calling of my reverse() function was completely pointless in the main() function haha

Answer (score 3):

## Never use `eval`. [Never.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Firstly, let me explain your mistakes. Your expectations about this program is wrong. You probably want `reverse(number)` to reverse the number itself. E.g. after `reverse(123)`, `123` should become `321`. But, wait, `123` is just a number, like a number in math, you know. Do you really want to `123` to become `321`? Can you predict what will happen after that? You will now pay `321` for a rent instead of `123`, because you have changed the number itself! Though, these are actually good news, because I have exactly `$123` on my bank account, and this is probably the easiest way to increase my money.

Well, this is just a joke. But the point is: you cannot change a number passed to the function. <s>This has been done for the security reasons</s>. There are mutable and immutable objects in python. Number is immutable. You cannot change a number, you can only assign another number:

```
a = 123
a = 312 # 123 is still 123, 321 is still 312, but a is 321 now
```

Lists are mutable objects, e.g:

```
a = []
a.append(1) # I can change the list itself, whoa!
a.append(2) # one more time
a = [3] # and even assign a new list
```

Finally, the main point is: you cannot change passed number to a function. **But**: you can return a new number! This is the point - just `return` a result from your `reverse` function and assign it somewhere like that:

```
def reverse(number):
    ...
    return result

r = reverse(123)
```

`reverse` wont change `123`, it wont break the world, it just returns a new number, and everything works fine.

By the way, there is a simpler way to check a palindrome:

```
In [5]: def is_palindrome(s):
   ...:     return s == s[::-1]
   ...: 

In [6]: n = input('Enter number: ')
Enter number: 123321

In [7]: if is_palindrome(n):
   ...:     print('You cool')
   ...: else:
   ...:     print('No luck')
   ...:     
You cool
```

`s[::-1]` means `take each symbol from the start till the end in a reverse order. This is a [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, have you considered representing the integer as a string and comparing it to its reversed form?

```
In [1]: num1 = 907709

In [2]: num2 = 90789

In [3]: str(num1) == str(num1)[::-1]
Out[3]: True

In [4]: str(num2) == str(num2)[::-1]
Out[4]: False
```

Addressing your current code: you need to *return* something from `reverse()`, and *assign* something to that returned value in `isPalindrome()`.

```
def reverse(number):
    rev = 0    
    while number > 0:
        endDigit = number % 10
        rev = (rev*10) + endDigit
        number = number // 10
    return rev

def isPalindrome(number):
    rev = reverse(number) 
    if number == rev:
        print("yep, it's a Palindrome")
    else:
        print("sorry man, not a Palindrome...")
```

That said, `reverse()` will still fail here.  Consider:

```
In [28]: reverse(10750)
Out[28]: 5701
```

If you don't consider this valid, you should use the string form of the integer (`str(number)`), which will retain trailing zeros when reversing the number.  Using `[::-1]` is a form of indexing to reverse a string.

Comment: Is there possibly a way to make some sort of an edit to my code and make it do what it's intended to?  Just a way to make my reverse() function available to be used inside of the isPalindrome() function

Comment: Okay I see, so it is completely necessary to change it to a string in order to find the palindromes.  Didn't think about the trailing zeros problem.